# SPI.H library to control APA102

Tags: spi, arduino-pro-mini

I am trying to run a strip of APA102 addressable LED's using a Mini pro.

The same strip I can run using a raspberry pi using SPI so I know the Strip works and what data I need to send to get it running.

My current code is as follows and I have striped it back to the bare minimum as I see it.

It all compiles and runs but nothing on the LED strip. The stip only has data and clock that should be connected to the CLK and Data in to connect to the MOSI.

All i want is to be able to send a 32bit value,

I had also tried

```
uint32_t value = 0xE0ffffff
```

but again no luck

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(9600);

  SPI.begin();

  byte start = 0x00;
  SPI.transfer(start);
  SPI.transfer(start);
  SPI.transfer(start);
  SPI.transfer(start);

  SPI.transfer(0xEF);
  SPI.transfer(255);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  SPI.transfer(10);
}
```

Comment: Check here https://www.pololu.com/product/2552/resources. The AdaFruit library may be configured for HW SPI.

Comment: I have played with that Libuary and it works fine but I dont see any were you can configure it to use SPI, you can switch to FastGPIO but not SPI.

Comment: As I said, check the AdaFruit library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_DotStar.

Comment: Apologies I clicked on the first Library, which was not the Adafruit one. Got it now and looking through it. Thank you

Comment: OK a fresh look and its all working OK now, I get a strange issue of when the code it uploaded to the Ardunio that random lights on the strip light up. but if I reset the Ardunio and power cycle the strip it all works as expected. Not sure what this behavior is but it only seems to happen after a upload when the serial link is connected. Anyhow thanks for the link, I am not using there library but looking though it I can see how they are doing it and they are doing a similar thing to me, i am writing 32bit vales using spi.transfer(buffer, size) and it seems to be good :)

Comment: I guess the random lights when uploading has to do with the SPI signals used while programming the flash. I would recommend disconnecting the LEDs while uploading, power down, connecting the LED and then powering up. Alternatively adding a chip select signal e.g. blocking the clock signal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55603/discussion-between-devilwah-and-mikael-patel).

Answer (score -1):

take a look at the datasheet, compare it vs. your code for any incompliance.

based on my quick reading, your code isn't consistent with the datasheet.

put the communications in a routine would help maintain uniformity.

Comment: Where is the issue with my code? the data sheet requires a 32bit start frame of zeros, followed by N number of Control fames which are them selves 32bit (brightness, RED, Green, Blue). once all control frames have been sent you need to send clock cycles to push the commands to the end of the strip (this is not needed for a single LED) . As I say the same frames work fine on a raspberry pi so its not the data structure thats an issue. As for putting it in a routine I will make this a libuary once I have the syntax right.